# Show only single column name from SQLite db in listview - Android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I need to set only first name field value in the listview.
Am querying data and getting all values and showing them in the listview. need to show only first name

The code,

```
    import c...l.Database.ItemCRUDOperations;
    import c...l.Model.Item;

    List<Item> items;

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    itemCrud = new ItemCRUDOperations(this);
    itemCrud.open();

    items = itemCrud.getAllItems(); // returns id, first name, last name ...
    // i need to only show first name in list view, currently it is showing all fields in listview
   //I tried items.getFirstName() as I have getters and setters to it but not getting the value.

    itemCrud.close();

    ArrayAdapter<Item> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Instead of Item ArrayList create String ArrayList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
...
List<String> firstNames = new ArrayList<>();
for (Item item : items) {
    firstNames.add(item.getFirstName);
}

ArrayAdapter<Item> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, firstNames);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Or you can simple override `toString()` method in your `Item` class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getFirstName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get a list with only firstName:

```
List<String> firstNamelist = new ArrayList<>();
for(Item item : items){
    firstnameList.add(item.getFirstName());
}
```

then pass firstNameList to adapter:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, firstNameList);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option already suggested in another answer is to create list of Strings and pass it to the adapter instead of list of Items.

Another, more general, way is to implement own list adapter, overriding method `getView` in it, like this:

```
class ItemListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView firstName;
        TextView lastName;
        // More fields ...
    }

    ItemListAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items) {
        super(context, 0, items);
    }

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public View getView(final int position, View view, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        final Item item = getItem(position);

        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (view == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);

            viewHolder.firstName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.first_name_text_view);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ItemListAdapter.ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.firstName.setText(item.getFirstName());
        return view;
    }
}
```

With this approach you will be able to add more information to the list item in future if you need.